# Why does my QuickLook show text files with a strange font, and how do I make it stop?

Tags: macos, quicklook

After updating to Yosemite*, I noticed that QuickLook now displays .txt and .log files like this:

[image: QuickLook misbehaving]

It still displays .plist files and other textual files like one would expect, with a small monospaced font on white background.

How can I make QuickLook display textual files in a more "traditional" way?

- = The Yosemite update might have been a coincidence, and I might just not have noticed it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have iA Writer installed on your Mac. They recently updated their application to include a Quick Look plugin to show some file types, including .txt, as multi markdown HTML in the Quick Look preview. People have complained that this is intrusive, and the developers have promised a fix in an upcoming update:

http://support.iawriter.com/help/discussions/mac-problems/3711-quick-look-plugin-is-too-liberal-with-file-formats

For now, you can simply delete iA Writer to stop this behavior or manually delete their Quick Look plugin from the app's bundle, as described at the end of this article:

http://brettterpstra.com/2012/03/19/multimarkdown-quick-look-with-style/

Comment: My hero! My savior! Thank you; this was driving me nuts! Just after your answer, I remembered there had to be a way to find out which QuickLook plugin was responsible for what, and sure enough, there is. In Terminal, type `qlmanage -m plugins`. After deleting the offending plugin, don't forget to run `qlmanage -r` to force QuickLook to apply the changes.

Comment: I've since written an expanded q&a on how to solve these kinds of issues yourself [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153595/how-can-i-see-which-quicklook-plugin-is-responsible-for-which-data-type/153596#153596).