# How to use custom font for codes in Quick Look?

Tags: finder, font, quicklook

When using Quick Look on a code file — `.swift` or `.cpp`, etc. — the font used to render the text seems to be *Menlo*. I was wondering if this is customizable. Can I manually set it to any font I want, such as *SF Mono* or *Source Code Pro*?

Comment: Is XCode actually setup as the default application for the filetypes you want to QuickLook?

Comment: Any other editors on the system with QuickLook plugins? Check with   [qlmanage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/153595/251859)

Comment: @LangLangC I used `qlmanage -l` and got a long list of generators. How do I find which generator is used to generate previews for which kind of files?

Comment: The list does just that. On my system TextMate claims the QL for these files; add `grep -i code` to get `public.source-code`. If you change frequently and the `/System`-QL doesn't pick it up instantly: `qlmanage -h` reveals `qlmanage -r` to reset QLdaemon. Find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11705425) the list of precedences.

Comment: TextMate is indeed responsible for the QuickLook preview on my Mac.  `public.source-code -> /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/TextMateQL.qlgenerator (1.0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Removed** the erroneous suggestion that it was Xcode font settings that provided this functionality.

You can find out which application is responsible for displaying source code in QuickLook by using this command in the terminal:

`qlmanage -m plugins | grep -i "public.source-code"`

If nothing shows up you don't have an application that provides this functionality.

In that case you can try this quicklook plugin https://github.com/anthonygelibert/QLColorCode.

Comment: Indeed nothing showed up, does this means QuickLook will fall back to system default font for codes?

Comment: That's my best guess. Menlo is the default non-proportional font, SF Mono is as far as I know only available in Xcode and Terminal as a selectable option. The QLColorCode plugin gives you the option to set the font to your of your choosing.